# Android Maps Compose | MarkerState.setMarker IllegalStateException

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I currently have an Android application built with Jetpack Compose on the Play Store with [android-maps-compose librairie](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose). For several days now, I've been receiving reports of recurring crashes from the Play Store, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end.

Here's the StackTrace:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerState.setMarker$maps_compose_release (Marker.kt:29)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerNode.onAttached (Marker.kt:5)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MapApplier.insertBottomUp (MapApplier.kt:13)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MapApplier.insertBottomUp (MapApplier.kt:13)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operation$PostInsertNodeFixup.execute (Operation.kt:26)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operations.executeAndFlushAllPendingOperations (Operations.kt:23)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.FixupList.executeAndFlushAllPendingFixups (FixupList.java:36)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operation$InsertSlotsWithFixups.execute (Operation.kt:36)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operations.executeAndFlushAllPendingOperations (Operations.kt:23)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.ChangeList.executeAndFlushAllPendingChanges (ChangeList.kt:3)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked (Composition.kt:50)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges (Composition.kt:6)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:174)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:174)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:7)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:48)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:48)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:48)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1648)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1659)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1129)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:1045)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1622)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8893)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:608)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

Below is the code for my screen used to display the map (simplified to include only the map part):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyMapsView(
    cameraPositionState: CameraPositionState,
) {

    val viewModel: AdaptedMapViewModel = koinViewModel()
    val darkTheme = appIsInDarkMode()
    val markerPositionStates = remember {
        mutableMapOf<Long, MarkerState>()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.init(darkTheme)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.markers.value) {
        viewModel.updateMarkerToDisplay()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.groups.value) {
        viewModel.updateMarkerToDisplay()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.sortMode.value) {
        viewModel.updateMarkerToDisplay()
    }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
            uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
                myLocationButtonEnabled = false, zoomControlsEnabled = false, mapToolbarEnabled = false
            ),
            properties = MapProperties(
                mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                    LocalContext.current, viewModel.mapStyle.value.rawResourceId
                ),
                mapType = viewModel.mapType.value
            )
        ) {

            MapMarkersAndCircles(viewModel, markerPositionStates)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MapMarkersAndCircles(
    viewModel: AdaptedMapViewModel, markerPositionStates: MutableMap<Long, MarkerState>
) {
    viewModel.markersToDisplay.value.forEach { marker ->

        if (markerPositionStates.containsKey(marker.id)) {
            markerPositionStates[marker.id]!!.position = marker.latLng()!!
        } else {
            markerPositionStates.putIfAbsent(
                marker.id, rememberMarkerState(
                    key = "${marker.id}",
                    position = marker.latLng()!!
                )
            )
        }
        MarkerComposable(
            keys = arrayOf(marker.id),
            tag = marker.id,
            state = markerPositionStates[marker.id]!!,
            anchor = if (marker.emoji.isNotEmpty()) Offset(0.5F, 0.5F) else Offset(0.5F, 1F),
            visible = viewModel.groups.value.find { it.id == marker.groupId }?.enable ?: true && marker.active,
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_marker_fill),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = markerColor(viewModel.mapStyle.value),
                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
            )
        }
        marker.circles.sortedByDescending { it.radius() }.forEach { circle ->
            MapCircle(viewModel, marker, circle)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MapCircle(viewModel: AdaptedMapViewModel, marker: FullDataMarker, circle: FullDataCircle) {
    return Circle(
        center = marker.latLng()!!,
        clickable = true,
        visible = viewModel.groups.value.find { it.id == marker.groupId }?.enable ?: true && marker.active && circle.active,
        fillColor = if (viewModel.circleStyle.value == CircleStyle.OUTLINE) Color.Transparent
        else Color(circle.color).copy(alpha = 0.3f),
        radius = circle.radius(),
    )
}

fun moveToLocation(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope, cameraPositionState: CameraPositionState, latLng: LatLng
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        cameraPositionState.animate(
            update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng), durationMs = 1000
        )
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the ViewModel (simplified to include only the map, markers, etc.):

```kotlin
class AdaptedMapViewModel(
    private val userPreferencesManager: UserPreferencesManager,
    private val appDataBaseManager: AppDataBaseManager,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _markersToDisplay = mutableStateOf((listOf<FullDataMarker>()))
    val markersToDisplay: State<List<FullDataMarker>> = _markersToDisplay

    private val _mapType = mutableStateOf(userPreferencesManager.defaultAppMapType())
    val mapType: State<MapType> = _mapType

    private val _mapStyle = mutableStateOf(MapStyle.STANDARD)
    val mapStyle: State<MapStyle> = _mapStyle

    private val _initiated = mutableStateOf(false)

    val sortMode: State<SortOrder> = userPreferencesManager.sortOrder

    val circleStyle = userPreferencesManager.circleStyle

    val markers = appDataBaseManager.markers
    val groups = appDataBaseManager.markerGroups


    fun init(darkTheme: Boolean) {
        if (_initiated.value) return
        _mapStyle.value = userPreferencesManager.defaultAppMapStyle(darkTheme)
        updateMarkerToDisplay()
        _initiated.value = true
    }

    fun updateMarkerToDisplay() {
        _markersToDisplay.value = markers.value
            .generalOrder(null, groups.value, sortMode.value)
            .filter { it.active }
    }

}
```

I suspect the issue may arise from the fact that the list of markers to display evolves over time, but I've already tried several approaches, and this one seems to "work best".

I added a tag and a key, used a list of MarketState: markerPositionStates to avoid having multiple states per marker (which was previously the case). I'm not sure what else to test at this point.

### Edit

After performing an update (for a completely different topic), the returned stack trace is no longer the same.
(I also updated some implementations, but not android-maps-compose directly)
Here it is:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: MarkerState may only be associated with one Marker at a time.
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerState.setMarker$maps_compose_release (Marker.kt:29)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MarkerNode.onAttached (Marker.kt:5)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MapApplier.insertBottomUp (MapApplier.kt:13)
  at com.google.maps.android.compose.MapApplier.insertBottomUp (MapApplier.kt:13)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operation$PostInsertNodeFixup.execute (Operation.kt:26)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operations.executeAndFlushAllPendingOperations (Operations.kt:23)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.FixupList.executeAndFlushAllPendingFixups (FixupList.java:36)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operation$InsertSlotsWithFixups.execute (Operation.kt:36)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.Operations.executeAndFlushAllPendingOperations (Operations.kt:23)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.changelist.ChangeList.executeAndFlushAllPendingChanges (ChangeList.kt:3)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked (Composition.kt:50)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges (Composition.kt:6)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:174)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke (Recomposer.kt:174)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:7)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:48)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch (AndroidUiDispatcher.java:48)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame (AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:48)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1648)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1659)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1129)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:1045)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1622)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8893)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:608)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

I'm not sure if the two are ultimately the same or not, but so far I've never had both at the same time. What I don't understand is that the only modification in the update has nothing to do with this part. So, I don't see why there would be a change in the stack trace.

The main problem is that I never manage to reproduce the bug on my side. Therefore, it's impossible for me to test before I find its origin (or else I deploy to a small portion of my audience to see if the problem persists).

Comment: From what I understand, `java.lang.IllegalStateException` is a runtime exception thrown in Java to indicate that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In simpler terms, you tried to use something in your code in a way that it wasn't designed for. From what I can see in your code, you had a nested `forEach` within another `forEach`, have you checked if this is the cause?

Comment: If you're trying to change the state of a marker after it has been removed from the map or after the relevant Compose UI element has been disposed of, you'll encounter this exception. Ensure that you're not trying to modify the marker state after the marker or the Compose UI element has been destroyed.
Probably just try key()
viewModel.markersToDisplay.value.forEach { marker ->
 key(markerState) {
//rest of code
}
}

Comment: @Yrll I don't think the error concerns the nested for loop because the problem (from what I understand) is directly related to MarkerComposable and its marker state. The other loop regarding circles and not a marker shouldn't pose any issues.

Comment: @SunilSunny If I understand correctly, you want me to replace `viewModel.markersToDisplay.value.forEach { marker` with `key(markerState)`. However, I cannot do that.

`markerState` is initially null and relies precisely on `markersToDisplay` to create the necessary states. Since `markersToDisplay` evolves over time (adding, modifying, deleting markers), `markerState` must also be updated accordingly. Therefore, I must rely on `markersToDisplay` to determine which markers to display.